# How to determine the number of days in a month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date, user-defined-functions

I need to determine the number of days in a month for a given date in SQL Server.

Is there a built-in function? If not, what should I use as the user-defined function?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use the following with the first day of the specified month:

```
datediff(day, @date, dateadd(month, 1, @date))
```

To make it work for every date:

```
datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date),
              dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date)))
```

Comment: Like Stan says this will give inaccurate results in some cases

Comment: But not for any given date as the OP wanted... ie 1/31/2009 returns 28

Comment: True, but it's very easy to workaround by adding `DAY(@date)-1` to the date.

Comment: don't you mean : 
datediff ( day , dateadd ( day , 1-day(@date) , @date) , dateadd ( month , 1 , dateadd ( day , 1-day(@date) , @date)))

Comment: It's a rare corner case, but I just stumbled into it: This will throw an error for December 9999.

Comment: This doesn't work for any date in Dec 9999. You get overflow on the date type. This worked for me in SQL Server 2014:

`case when datediff(m, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date), convert(date, convert(datetime, 2958463))) > 0 then datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date), dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date))) else 31 end`

Comment: All of the solutions mentioned here pale in comparison to the elegance of [@Mikael Eriksson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14660557/2738164).  That works whenever a valid date is provided without crazy workarounds for niche cases and is far simpler code - I'd highly recommend anyone on T-SQL stick to getting the `day` component of the `eomonth` output.

Answer (score 196):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use [EOMONTH (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) to get the last day of the month and then you can use [DAY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) to get the number of days in the month.

```
DECLARE @ADate DATETIME

SET @ADate = GETDATE()

SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(@ADate)) AS DaysInMonth
```

Comment: And if you need the number of days in a given, you could also use the DATEFROMPARTS method. The code above would become SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1))) AS DaysInMonth

Comment: The beauty of this solution comes into play if @ADate is a complex calculated value ! +1

Answer (score 31):

Most elegant solution: works for any ***@DATE***

```
DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@DATE),0)))
```

Throw it in a function or just use it inline. This answers the original question without all the extra junk in the other answers.

examples for dates from other answers:

`SELECT DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,'1/31/2009'),0)))` ***Returns 31***

`SELECT DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,'2404-feb-15'),0)))` ***Returns 29***

`SELECT DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,'2011-12-22'),0)))` ***Returns 31***

Answer (score 12):

```
--Last Day of Previous Month
SELECT DATEPART(day, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)))

--Last Day of Current Month
SELECT DATEPART(day, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))

--Last Day of Next Month
SELECT DATEPART(day, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0)))
```

Personally though, I would make a UDF for it if there is not a built in function...

Answer (score 9):

**I would suggest:**

```
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: datepart doesn't return number of days  and your answer is also wrong

Comment: Worked for me, but sure using the day function would be a more clean answer

Comment: this answer is almost identical to the one below with votes of 75.

Comment: This is also the correct answer as `EOMONTH(GETDATE())` will return the end of the month date and the `DAY` function will return the day part from that month (in case of last day of month, it will be number of days in the month)

Answer (score 3):

This code gets you the number of days in current month:

```
SELECT datediff(dd,getdate(),dateadd(mm,1,getdate())) as datas
```

Change `getdate()` to the date you need to count days for.

Answer (score 2):

```
   --- sql server below 2012---
    select day( dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, 1, convert(date,'2019-03-01'))))
    -- this for sql server 2012--
    select day(EOMONTH(getdate()))
```

Answer (score 2):

use SQL Server EOMONTH Function nested with day to get last day of month

```
select Day(EOMONTH('2020-02-1')) -- Leap Year returns 29
select Day(EOMONTH('2021-02-1')) -- returns 28
select Day(EOMONTH('2021-03-1')) -- returns 31
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need to add a function, but it's a simple one.  I use this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetDaysInMonth] ( @pDate    DATETIME )

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET @pDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pDate, 101)
    SET @pDate = @pDate - DAY(@pDate) + 1

    RETURN DATEDIFF(DD, @pDate, DATEADD(MM, 1, @pDate))
END

GO
```

Comment: The combination of DATEDIFF and DATEADD, by the way, doesn't always work.  If you put a date of 1/31/2009 into it, the DATEADD will return 2/28/2009 and the DATEDIFF gives you 28, rather than 31.

Comment: how to check, i mean what to execute to check the days in a month ??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Datediff(day,
(Convert(DateTime,Convert(varchar(2),Month(getdate()))+'/01/'+Convert(varchar(4),Year(getdate())))),
(Convert(DateTime,Convert(varchar(2),Month(getdate())+1)+'/01/'+Convert(varchar(4),Year(getdate()))))) as [No.of Days in a Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Find the number of days in whatever month we're currently in**

```
DECLARE @dt datetime
SET     @dt = getdate()

SELECT @dt AS [DateTime],
       DAY(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, -1, @dt), -1)) AS [Days in Month]
```

**Solution 2: Find the number of days in a given month-year combo**

```
DECLARE @y int, @m int
SET     @y = 2012
SET     @m = 2

SELECT @y AS [Year],
       @m AS [Month],
       DATEDIFF(DAY,
                DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m, ((@y - 1900) * 12) + @m - 1, 0)),
                DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m, ((@y - 1900) * 12) + @m, 0))
               ) AS [Days in Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  datediff(day, 
        dateadd(day, 0, dateadd(month, ((2013 - 1900) * 12) + 3 - 1, 0)),
        dateadd(day, 0, dateadd(month, ((2013  - 1900) * 12) + 3, 0))
        )
```

Nice  Simple and does not require creating any functions Work Fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function, but it is for your own convenience. It works perfect and I never encountered any faulty computations using this function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_days](@date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    SET @date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date)
    DECLARE @result int = (select DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@date), @date)))
    RETURN @result
END
```

**How it works:** subtracting the date's day number from the date itself gives you the last day of previous month. So, you need to add one month to the given date, subtract the day number and get the day component of the result.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1) -  trunc(sysdate,'MM') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Mehrdad, but this works as well. :)

```
CREATE function dbo.IsLeapYear
(
    @TestYear int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Result bit
    set @Result = 
    cast(
        case when ((@TestYear % 4 = 0) and (@testYear % 100 != 0)) or (@TestYear % 400 = 0)
        then 1
        else 0
        end
    as bit )
    return @Result
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDaysInMonth
(
    @TestDT datetime
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result int 
    DECLARE @MonthNo int

    Set @MonthNo = datepart(m,@TestDT)

    Set @Result = 
    case @MonthNo
        when  1 then 31
        when  2 then 
            case 
                when dbo.IsLeapYear(datepart(yyyy,@TestDT)) = 0
                then 28
                else 29
            end
        when  3 then 31
        when  4 then 30
        when  5 then 31
        when  6 then 30
        when  7 then 31
        when  8 then 31
        when  9 then 30 
        when 10 then 31
        when 11 then 30 
        when 12 then 31
    end

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

To Test

```
declare @testDT datetime;

set @testDT = '2404-feb-15';

select dbo.GetDaysInMonth(@testDT)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another one...

```
Select Day(DateAdd(day, -Day(DateAdd(month, 1, getdate())), 
                         DateAdd(month, 1, getdate())))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I thought I would share what I'm using.

```
DECLARE @date date = '2011-12-22'

/* FindFirstDayOfMonth - Find the first date of any month */
-- Replace the day part with -01
DECLARE @firstDayOfMonth date = CAST( CAST(YEAR(@date) AS varchar(4)) + '-' + 
                                      CAST(MONTH(@date) AS varchar(2)) + '-01' AS date)
SELECT @firstDayOfMonth
```

and

```
DECLARE @date date = '2011-12-22'

/* FindLastDayOfMonth - Find what is the last day of a month - Leap year is handled by DATEADD */
-- Get the first day of next month and remove a day from it using DATEADD
DECLARE @lastDayOfMonth date = CAST( DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, FindFirstDayOfMonth(@date))) AS date)

SELECT @lastDayOfMonth
```

Those could be combine to create a single function to retrieve the number of days in a month if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DAY(SUBDATE(ADDDATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '-1'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Nice 'n' Simple and does not require creating any functions

Comment: This is for SQL Server; I've never heard of a `subdate` function.

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad Afshari reply is most accurate one, apart from usual this answer is based on formal mathematical approach given by Curtis McEnroe in his blog https://cmcenroe.me/2014/12/05/days-in-month-formula.html

```
DECLARE @date  DATE= '2015-02-01'
DECLARE @monthNumber TINYINT 
DECLARE @dayCount TINYINT
SET @monthNumber = DATEPART(MONTH,@date )
SET @dayCount = 28 + (@monthNumber + floor(@monthNumber/8)) % 2 + 2 %    @monthNumber + 2 * floor(1/@monthNumber)   
SELECT @dayCount + CASE WHEN @dayCount = 28 AND DATEPART(YEAR,@date)%4 =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- leap year adjustment
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the no. of days in a month we can directly use Day() available in SQL.

Follow the link posted at the end of my answer for SQL Server 2005 / 2008.

The following example and the result are from SQL 2012

```
alter function dbo.[daysinm]
(
@dates nvarchar(12)
)
returns int
as
begin
Declare @dates2 nvarchar(12)
Declare @days int
begin
select @dates2 = (select DAY(EOMONTH(convert(datetime,@dates,103))))
set @days = convert(int,@dates2)
end
return @days
end

--select dbo.daysinm('08/12/2016')
```

Result in SQL Server SSMS

```
  (no column name)
1 31
```

Process:

When EOMONTH is used, whichever the date format we use it is converted into DateTime format of SQL-server. Then the date output of EOMONTH() will be 2016-12-31 having 2016 as Year, 12 as Month and 31 as Days.
This output when passed into Day() it gives you the total days count in the month.

If we want to get the instant result for checking we can directly run the below code,

```
select DAY(EOMONTH(convert(datetime,'08/12/2016',103)))
```

or

```
select DAY(EOMONTH(convert(datetime,getdate(),103)))
```

for reference to work in SQL Server 2005/2008/2012, please follow the following external link ...

[Find No. of Days in a Month in SQL](https://raresql.com/2013/01/06/sql-server-get-number-of-days-in-month/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE(); --or '12/1/2018' (month/day/year) 
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH ( @date )) AS 'This Month'; 
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH ( @date, 1 )) AS 'Next Month';
```

result:
This Month
31

Next Month
30

Comment: this doesn't return the number of days in the month

Comment: Yes it does. But only for SQL Server 2012 and above

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @m int
SET     @m = 2

SELECT 
       @m AS [Month],
       DATEDIFF(DAY,
                DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m, +@m -1, 0)),
                DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(m,+ @m, 0))
               ) AS [Days in Month]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RETURN day(dateadd(month, 12 * @year + @month - 22800, -1)) 
select day(dateadd(month, 12 * year(date) + month(date) - 22800, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of implementing this is using the `datefromparts` function to construct the first day of the month, and calculate the days from there.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DaysInMonth]
(
    @year INT,
    @month INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

IF @month < 1 OR @month > 12 RETURN NULL;
IF @year < 1753 OR @year > 9998 RETURN NULL;

DECLARE @firstDay DATE = datefromparts(@year, @month, 1);
DECLARE @lastDay DATE = dateadd(month, 1, @firstDay);

RETURN datediff(day, @firstDay, @lastDay);

END
GO
```

Similarily, you can calculate the days in a year:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DaysInYear]
(
    @year INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

IF @year < 1753 OR @year > 9998 RETURN NULL;

DECLARE @firstDay DATE = datefromparts(@year, 1, 1);
DECLARE @lastDay DATE = dateadd(year, 1, @firstDay);

RETURN datediff(day, @firstDay, @lastDay);

END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

For any date

```
select DateDiff(Day,@date,DateAdd(month,1,@date))
```

Answer (score -1):

select first_day=dateadd(dd,-1*datepart(dd,getdate())+1,getdate()), 
last_day=dateadd(dd,-1*datepart(dd,dateadd(mm,1,getdate())),dateadd(mm,1,getdate())),
no_of_days = 1+datediff(dd,dateadd(dd,-1*datepart(dd,getdate())+1,getdate()),dateadd(dd,-1*datepart(dd,dateadd(mm,1,getdate())),dateadd(mm,1,getdate())))

replace any date with getdate to get the no of months in that particular date

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @Month INT=2,
    @Year INT=1989
DECLARE @date DateTime=null
SET @date=CAST(CAST(@Year AS nvarchar) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS nvarchar) + '-' + '1' AS DATETIME);

DECLARE @noofDays TINYINT 
DECLARE @CountForDate TINYINT
SET @noofDays = DATEPART(MONTH,@date )
SET @CountForDate = 28 + (@noofDays + floor(@noofDays/8)) % 2 + 2 %    @noofDays + 2 * floor(1/@noofDays)   
SET @noofDays= @CountForDate + CASE WHEN @CountForDate = 28 AND DATEPART(YEAR,@date)%4 =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
PRINT @noofDays
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @date nvarchar(20)
SET @date ='2012-02-09 00:00:00'
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,cast(replace(cast(YEAR(@date) as char)+'-'+cast(MONTH(@date) as char)+'-01',' ','')+' 00:00:00' as datetime),dateadd(month,1,cast(replace(cast(YEAR(@date) as char)+'-'+cast(MONTH(@date) as char)+'-01',' ','')+' 00:00:00' as datetime)))
```

Answer (score -2):

simple query in SQLServer2012 :

select day(('20-05-1951 22:00:00'))

i tested for many dates and it return always a correct result

Comment: SELECT DAY(CAST('1951-05-20' AS DATE)) returns 20 which is the day portion of the date. It does not return the number of days in the month of May.