# how to calculate number of days in year in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the number of days in year in SQL server 2008 management studio.

For Example:

- 2016 : 366
- 2014 : 365

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318586/how-to-get-number-of-days-from-month-and-year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
  declare @y int;
  set @y = 2014;

  SELECT DATEDIFF(day,  cast(@y as char(4)),  cast(@y+1 as char(4))) Days
```

Result:

```
Days
365
```

2Version by comment:

```
 declare @y int;
 set @y = 2014;

 SELECT DATEDIFF(day,  cast(cast(@y as char(4)) as date),  cast(cast(@y+1 as char(4)) as date)) DaysCnt
```

Comment: Better would be to explicitly declare data type lengths (you can get bitten by the default length of 30 sometimes and 1 sometimes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131499/what-is-the-effect-of-omitting-size-in-nvarchar-declaration).
Also, you don't need NVARCHAR, VARCHAR should do the trick.
Last, if you explicitly cast to DATEs it might be easier for the person who will have to possibly troubleshoot (and understand the code) later.

Ex: DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,  CAST(CAST(@Year AS CHAR(4))  AS DATE),  CAST( CAST(@Year + 1 AS CHAR(4))  AS DATE)) AS Days_cnt;

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
create function fn(@year varchar(20))
returns int
as
begin   
declare @a int
select @a =DATEPART(dy,@year +'1231')
return @a
end

select dbo.fn('2014')--365
select dbo.fn('2016')--366
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bff56/2)

Answer (score 2):

For SQL 2012 and later:

```
DECLARE @FromDateYear INT = YEAR(GETDATE());
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@FromDateYear),1,1), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@FromDateYear) + 1,1,1))
```

You can simply substitute the `YEAR(GETDATE())` with your year value.

All this is doing is calculating the number of days from 1 Jan of the current year and 1 Jan of the next year.  This will include Feb 29 if it exists in the current year.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
begin  
  declare @y int  
  set @y=2014  

  select datepart(dayofyear,dateadd(day,-1,'1/1/'+convert(char(4),@y+1)))  
end
```

I'm getting day 1 of the next year, subtracting one day to get the last day of the current year, then getting the day-of-year from that.