# Count days of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is anyway to count the number of days in a month in SQL server 2008... Something similar to this Javascript code I wrote:

```
 function daysInMonth(month, year) {
                    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
                }

                var dateForApp = new Date();
                var MonthForApp = (dateForApp.getMonth() + 1);
                var yearForApp = dateForApp.getFullYear();

                var daysofMonth = new Array();

                for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth(MonthForApp, yearForApp); i++) {
                    daysofMonth.push(parseInt(i));
                } // Resulting in something like this (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...etc)
```

I now need to figure out how to do this in SQL... I so far have the foolowing:

```
declare @Date datetime
select @Date = Getdate()

select datepart(dd,dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(mm,1,cast(cast(year(@Date) as varchar)+'-'+cast(month(@Date) as varchar)+'-01' as datetime))))
```

which will let me know how many days there are (31) in the month, but I am now not quite sure how to get the actual counting up done... I was trying while loops etc, but have had no success. Has anyone got any ideas or a thread they could point me to? (I found nothing while searching the net)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... but that thread tells me how to get how many Days there are in the month? EG: (31) for March... I know how to get this... What I am after is, now that I have my 31, how do I build an Array / Result set of .. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11......31

Comment: There aren't arrays in sql

Comment: @Bobby, I know this... But for explaining the question I need to give you an idea of what I am trying to create... forget array then... how do I build a Resultset with that information then?

Comment: Maybe create a temporary table and inside a loop insert your days in one at a time

Comment: @Mike sorry I thought you wanted just the total, added an answer for a set of days

Comment: Your question is NOT clear.  If there are no arrays in SQL, it's not obvious what you want.  Do you want to return a Row with X (31) columns?  Do you want to return X (31) rows?  And for both of those, containing what data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE can provide a days table;

```
declare @date datetime = '01 feb 1969'
declare @days int = datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1 - day(@date), @date),
                    dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(@date), @date)))

;with days(day) as
(
    select 1 as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from days
        where day < @days
)
select day from days
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  using [DATEDIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691022/how-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-sql-server)?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DaysInMonth INT
SET @DaysInMonth = 31

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1

DECLARE @temp TABLE([Days] INT)

WHILE @i <= @DaysInMonth
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @temp
    VALUES(@i)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT *
FROM @temp
```

Comment: Probably not the nicest way of doing it but you get all the days you want