# Total Number of days of a Month

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to write a query which returns *No. of days* of a Month. 
**Please understand that I cannot use DATE, and any query having DATE will not work.**

I have created a parameter which takes int value. Like January is 1, February is 2 etc.

From the values 1 or 2, I wanted to get the number of days like the number of days of 1 should be 31 and 2 should be 28 or 29.

I am using Ms sql-server-2008.

Help is required.

Regards,

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691022/how-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the number of days in a month in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691022/how-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-sql-server)

Comment: Looks like we found the same thing!

Comment: See my question is to get the total number of days from a int value, no DATE is mention here. and I cannot use Date.

Comment: Why can't you use date? You can build a date value using the month number and just use datediff to determine the number of days, what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: its demand of the customer to enter the year and month in separate Fields and he asked to enter in numbers.

Comment: I do understand, but you can build a date using that information and use that calculated value to determine the length of the month

Comment: yes, Thanks alot. that is a great help. I didn't even think about it.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can always build a date using date parts. You may want to validate the input and transform this logic to your needs.

```
DECLARE @year SMALLINT = 2017;
DECLARE @month TINYINT = 2;

DECLARE @dateFrom DATE = CONVERT(DATE, 
      CONVERT(CHAR(4), @year) + '-'
    + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @month), 2)
    + '-01'
);

DECLARE @dateTo DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @dateFrom);

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateFrom, @dateTo);
```

-- OR --

If you are really keen to not use any calculation, just a query, store these values in a table and query that table using the input values.

Comment: Thanks alot Pred. that server the purpose. you have save a lot of my time.