# How to get number of days in a month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get the number of days in a month in SQL Server, if we input the month number or month name, or even a date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the number of days in a month in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691022/how-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
select day(eomonth ('2018-02-01')) as NoOfDays
```

and the result will be:

```
NoOfDays
-----------
28
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have a date, then simply do:

```
select day(eomonth(date))
```

If you have a month number, then:

```
select day(eomonth(datefromparts(2020, month_number, 1)))
```

Comment: @CodeMachine . . . You are the OP and can accept whichever answer you like.  However, I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer for an equivalent answer posted several minutes later.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a date and are on 2012 or later :

```
SELECT day(eomonth(yourdate))
```

Month name / number is automatically prone to an error when dealing with February - do you consider it 28 or 29, which year are you referring to when making that calculation etc.

Comment: 2012+. This will break in versions 2008.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using sql-server 2008 or earlier:

Date as input

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = getdate()

SELECT day(dateadd(m, datediff(m, -1, @date), -1))
```

Month and year as input

```
DECLARE @year  INT = 2018
DECLARE @month INT = 2

SELECT day(dateadd(m, @month + datediff(m, 0, cast(@year as char(4))), -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
SELECT day(eomonth(yourdate))
```

Answer (score 2):

for pre 2012 where `eomonth()` is not available

if you have a date

```
select  day(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date) + 1, -1))
```

if you have the year & month

```
declare @year   int = 2018,
        @month  int = 8
select  dateadd(month, @month, dateadd(year, @year - 1900, -1))
```