# How to determine number of days in a month in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I have data with date, userid, and amount. I want to calculate sum(amount) divided by total day for each month. the final will be presented in monthly basis.

The table I have is looks like this

```
date       userid  amount
2019-01-01  111  10
2019-01-15  112  20
2019-01-20  113  10
2019-02-01  114  30
2019-02-15  111  20
2019-03-01  115  40
2019-03-23  155  50
```

desired result is like this

```
date    avg_qty_sol
Jan-19  1.29
Feb-19  1.79
Mar-19  2.90
```

avg_qty_sold is coming from sum(amount) / total day for respective month
e.g for jan 2019 sum amount is 40 and total days in jan is 31. so the avg_qty_sold is 40/31

Currently Im using case when for this solution. is there any better approach to this?

Comment: I guess this post answer to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691022/how-to-determine-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Presto 318, you this is as easy as:

```
SELECT day(last_day_of_month(some_date))
```

See https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#last_day_of_month

Before Presto 318, You can combine [`date_trunc`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc) with [`EXTRACT`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#extract):

- `date_trunc('month', date_value))` gives beginning of the month, while `date_add('month', 1, date_trunc('month', date_value))` gives beginning of the next month
- subtracting `date` values returns an `interval day to second`
- `EXTRACT(DAY FROM interval)` returns day-portion of the interval. You can also use `day` convenience function instead of `EXTRACT(DAY FROM ...)`. The `EXTRACT` syntax is more verbose and more standard.

```
presto:default> SELECT
             ->     date_value,
             ->     EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
             ->         date_add('month', 1, date_trunc('month', date_value)) - date_trunc('month', date_value)))
             -> FROM (VALUES DATE '2019-01-15', DATE '2019-02-01') t(date_value);
 date_value | _col1
------------+-------
 2019-01-15 |    31
 2019-02-01 |    28
(2 rows)
```

Less natural, but a bit shorter alternative would be to get day number for the last day of given month with `day(date_add('day', -1, date_add('month', 1, date_trunc('month', date_value))))`:

```
presto:default> SELECT
             ->     date_value,
             ->     day(date_add('day', -1, date_add('month', 1, date_trunc('month', date_value))))
             -> FROM (VALUES DATE '2019-01-15', DATE '2019-02-01') t(date_value);
 date_value | _col1
------------+-------
 2019-01-15 |    31
 2019-02-01 |    28
(2 rows)
```

Comment: @muhnandap i found a shorter alternative and updated the answer.